# Nested inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, nested

For an instance, I have classes like this:

```
class MyClassA{
   protected $variableA='this is var A';
   public $variableB='this is var B';
   //some function here
}

class MyClassB extends MyClassA{
   //some function here
}

class MyClassC extends MyClassB{
   //some function here
}

class MyClassD extends MyClassC{
   //some function here
}
```

How can I get `$variableA` and `$variableB` from `MyClassD`?

Answer (score 3):

Just reference them in any class using `$this`.

```
class MyClassD extends MyClassC {
    function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->variableA; 
        echo $this->variableB;
    }
}

$var = new MyClassD;
```

[See it work!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vrE2ps)

Answer (score 1):

Since `variableA` is public in the base class, you can just access it directly like so: `$MyClassDObj->variableB`.

Since `variableA` is protected, *you need to write a getter if you wanted to access it from outside the class*, otherwise from within class D, you can access it just like variableB.  A getter would look like this:

```
public function getVariableA()
{
    return $this->variableA;
}
```

And then you call `$MyClassDObj->getVariableA()`;

Comment: If `variableA` were private, you'd need a getter. `protected` does not require a getter.

Comment: Protected is the same as private except that protected variables are accessible from derived classes, private variables are not, therefore it still requires a getter for access outside the class.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Drew, unfortunately you are mistaken. See [my example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vrE2ps), no getter required.

Comment: I know that, but I said if he wanted to access it from outside the class he would need a getter.  He didn't really clarify in the question.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: OH! My mistake. Then of course you are correct! Referencing these protected variables from outside of the class requires a getter. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's late, were all tired :)  I should have given up hours ago lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you'd get it from MyClassA.